# What was the STS mid-deck cargo capacity?

Tags: space-shuttle, payload

What was the normal cargo capacity of the Shuttle mid-deck, in terms of mass and volume?

STS-135 apparently carried more than usual in the mid-deck, how much and how?

Comment: Source of "STS-135 apparently carried more than usual in the mid-deck"?

Comment: somewhere on nasa.gov @OrganicMarble -- of course, I can't find it now, but there's [Resultingly, compared to previous shuttle missions to the Space Station, additional storage space was available.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-135#Down-mass_payload) Also, when trying to find where I read it I found several sources saying it was just over a tonne

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm not sure there is really a straightforward answer to this question - like a lot of shuttle things, the rules about middeck payloads were complicated.